# App is showing two menustrip instead of one

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new in c# coding, hope this question doesn't bother anyone :)

I am trying to learn about using user control in win forms. In the below code, when I am running my code it shows 2 menustrip instead of one.

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    //user control
    private mdi2.UserControls.UCForm1 ucForm1;
    private mdi2.UserControls.UCForm2 ucForm2;
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        InitializeComponent();
    // Instantiate the User Controls
    ucForm1 = new mdi2.UserControls.UCForm1();
    this.Controls.Add(ucForm1);
    ucForm2 = new mdi2.UserControls.UCForm2();
    this.Controls.Add(ucForm2);
    }

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void uCForm1ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ucForm1.Visible = true;
        ucForm1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        ucForm1.BringToFront();
    }

    private void uCForm2ToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         ucForm2.Visible = true;
         ucForm2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
         ucForm2.BringToFront();
    }
}
```

[image: user controls showing twice]

Comment: Sorry i forgot about the code.

Comment: Why are you calling `InitializeComponent()` twice?

Comment: thanks.         It was a copy-paste mistake.

Comment: Yea, if you do `InitializeComponent()` 5 times - you'll see more menus!

Answer (score 4):

It's difficult to tell you what the problem is because **[we](https://stackoverflow.com/users)** do not know anything about `mdi2.UserControls.UCForm1`

Based upon the first look on your code:

- `InitializeComponent()` is called twice

Hope this helps.

Comment: Also both are added to this.Controls and they are visible by default.

Comment: @Don I would suggest you to suggest an [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34547829/edit)?